# Gutenberg Blocks - Change EDIT part of the block using editor.BlockEdit filters. How to change the markup?

Tags: plugins, filters, block-editor

I want to edit the `core/heading` block so it changes it's markup from
`<h1>Hello world</h1>` to `<h1><span>Hello world</span></h1>`. Note the `<span>` element in between.

The code below does not work as it should. It adds the span outside the block, as a wrapper.
`<span><h1>Hello world</h1></span>`. Is there a way to alter the `<BlockEdit/>` element? And goal should be to not add the span element into the content field.

Thought, if altering the edit part, should I also mirror this on the save part?

```
const { createHigherOrderComponent } = wp.compose;
const { Fragment } = wp.element;
const { InspectorControls } = wp.blockEditor;
const { PanelBody } = wp.components;

const withInspectorControls =  createHigherOrderComponent( ( BlockEdit ) => {

    return ( props ) => {

        if (props.name !== "core/heading") {
            return <BlockEdit { ...props } />;
        }
        
        return (
            <Fragment>
                <span>
                    <BlockEdit { ...props } />
                </span>
            </Fragment>
        );
    };
}, "withInspectorControl" );

wp.hooks.addFilter( 'editor.BlockEdit', 'my-plugin/with-inspector-controls', withInspectorControls );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately there is now way to alter the markup of an existing block apart from *wrapping* it in additional markup:

> It receives the original block BlockEdit component and returns a new wrapped component.
> Source: https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/developers/filters/block-filters/#editor-blockedit

To achieve what you want in the editor currently the only way would be to create your own version of the heading block replacing the core one.

But what you can do, and probably is the better way to do it anyway since you leave the default markup in the DB in place, is change the markup on render using the [`render_block`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/render_block/) filter.

You can then either use regular expressions or something more solid like a DOM Parser (e.g. https://github.com/wasinger/htmlpagedom) to alter the markup on output any way you like.

```
<?php
add_filter('render_block', function ($blockContent, $block) {

    if ($block['blockName'] !== 'core/heading') {
        return $blockContent;
    }           

    $pattern = '/(<h[^>]*>)(.*)(<\/h[1-7]{1}>)/i';
    $replacement = '$1<span>$2</span>$3';
    return preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $blockContent);

}, 10, 2);
```

I've also written [a blog post](https://kraftner.com/en/blog/the-taming-of-the-block-part-ii-the-practical-part/#post-processing-with-render-filters) on various ways to configure Gutenberg that also covers the `render_block` filter and some reasoning around it in case you want to dig deeper.

Comment: Thanks, I'll go with the php filter for now. I've seen it, but I don't like it has to be done dynamically on render. I would have preferred it would write the static code to the DB. but yeah, I might replace the core block with an altered clone. Thanks for the quick response and the elaborate answer.

Comment: As of Wordpress 6.1 it's possible to create your own block variation of an existing block. See for a complete example: https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/block-tutorial/extending-the-query-loop-block/

Comment: @AFS Can you elaborate how this can help here? As far as I see it this allows variations of attributes, but not the markup. If I am wrong could you please add the details for this specific question as another answer?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do just that by using `blocks.registerBlockType` filter. For a detailed explanation, refer [to this article by Jim Schofield](https://jschof.com/gutenberg-blocks/using-gutenberg-filters-to-extend-blocks/)

However, instead of calling default edit and save functions wrapped in custom code (like in the article), do not call them, just provide your own code.